# Disabling underscore-to-subscript in Emacs Org-Mode export

Tags: emacs, latex, tex, org-mode

When I export to PDF via org-mode (C-c C-e d), any words with underscores end up being partially converted to subscript. How can I prevent this from happening?

I found this article on the subject:

[Disabling Underscore subscript in Emacs Tex Mode](http://gimbo.org.uk/blog/2007/11/11/disabling_underscore_subscript_emacs_tex_mode/)

However, I either wasn't able to figure out the correct elisp or it simply didn't work. Note, I don't want to change any global font options. I only want this fix to apply to tex/latex/org-mode.

I also found this post, though it didn't work either:

[disable subscript superscript raise/lower?](http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.emacs.help/browse_thread/thread/bfc9141338bde20b)

Comment: `org-toggle-pretty-entities` for ppl where subscripts are annoying (or desired) directly inside an org doc (not related to OPs question about exporting though, just, this was a top google hit and figured I'd contribute).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by setting the following variable:

```
(setq org-export-with-sub-superscripts nil)
```

Answer (score 106):

You can disable super/subscripting within an org file by adding the following line:

```
#+OPTIONS: ^:nil
```

Check the org manual for more options.
The following command inserts a template containing all the options:
    `C-c C-e #`

Comment: you can also have '^:{}' this will still allow you to have subscript if you use curly braces, i.e. my_var won't give you subscript but F_{t} will. See also the org-mode manual: http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-options.html#Export-options

Comment: There are some other options not on the C-c C-e t template:

#+OPTIONS:   author:nil email:nil creator:nil timestamp:nil

Comment: Is this supposed to work in Org v.8+? It seems to have stopped working after I upgraded.

Comment: Corrected link from @danielpoe: http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html#Export-settings

Comment: @danielpoe Your link is broken.

Answer (score 8):

I think this would be easier: http://orgmode.org/manual/Subscripts-and-superscripts.html
Escape the underscore with a backslash:

[image]

[image]

Now, escape the _:

[image]

[image]

You can see this in action here: http://www.railsonmaui.com/blog/2013/04/27/octopress-setup-with-github-and-org-mode/

Comment: Sorry for offtopic, but what color scheme do you use? I quite like it.

Comment: zenburn -- awesome. Use package-list-packages. It's a bit like railscasts.

Comment: thanks! And comments must be at least 15 characters in length.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me in org 8.2.10, whether I'm publishing to HTML or to LaTeX/PDF.  I get a backslash in the output, plus subscript text.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work when publishing to html. using org  8.2.10m same behavior as @KenWilliams noted

Comment: For submitting org bug reports follow instructions at http://orgmode.org/manual/Feedback.html.

Comment: @KenWilliams did you ever find a solution for publishing underscores to HTML?

Answer (score 6):

Use `\under` (Documentation on [The Org Manual: Special symbols](https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-symbols.html#Special-symbols))

For example:

```
text\under{}text
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you want to prevent subscripts in the onscreen display of the source file or in the text of the output PDF? If the latter, then you want

```
\usepackage{underscore}
```

It won't break the use of underscores in maths mode, either.

Answer (score 4):

For individual cases, insert a literal underscore this way:

```
text text one\textunderscore{}two text
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case any word that contains an underscore is likely to be a variable name or something similar. I just surround it with `=` or `~` so that it's treated as such. Then it will be exported accordingly.