# make Org ignore underscores when exporting to HTML

Tags: emacs, formatting, org-mode

I use Emacs Org-mode to write some documents, and I describe some files like “/path/to/file_blah.conf”.

After I hit `c-c c-e h` to export one of those files to HTML, all the filenames in that file containing `_` become small subscript words.

How can I make Org-mode ignore the underscores, so that I can see the filenames on the HTML page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on top of your file put the following line and save. reopen the file or hit C-c C-c on that line

```
#+OPTIONS: ^:nil
```

BTW: what is there in your org-emphasis-alist. C-h v `org-emphasis-alist`. You might need to edit that to achieve output to your liking

Comment: it works, thank you.
org-emphasis-alist is a variable defined in `org.el'.
Its value is (("*" bold "<b>" "</b>")
 ("/" italic "<i>" "</i>")
 ("_" underline "<span style=\"text-decoration:underline;\">" "</span>")
 ("=" org-code "<code>" "</code>" verbatim)
 ("~" org-verbatim "<code>" "</code>" verbatim)
 ("+"
  (:strike-through t)
  "<del>" "</del>"))

Comment: The documentation for this feature is in [“Export options” in the Org-mode manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-options.html). As that page explains, `#+OPTIONS:` lets you set various export options. The `^:` option lets you “turn on/off TeX-like syntax for sub- and superscripts” when given the values `t` or `nil`.

Answer (score 5):

Duplicated as [Disabling underscore-to-subscript in Emacs Org-Mode export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698562/disabling-underscore-to-subscript-in-emacs-org-mode-export/701201#701201)

```
(setq org-export-with-sub-superscripts nil)
```

in `.emacs` or

```
#+OPTIONS: ^:nil
```

in org file.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution should be to correctly markup the paths, so:

```
Open the file =/path/to/fileA= or ~c:/path/to/fileB~.
```