# Emacs org-mode: specify raw area for HTML exporter

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode

I have a problem when exporting org-mode buffers to html. The following table is not properly exported:

```
|-------+----------------+----------|
| HOST  | DB             | COMMENTS |
|-------+----------------+----------|
| rhea  | numbering_test |          |
| rhea  | phones         |          |
| dione | phonenumbers   |          |
| dione | numbering_test |          |
|-------+----------------+----------|
```

The problem is that the underscore tells the HTML exported to use subscripts. This is not what I want. I want `numbering_test` to appear like normal text.

The same problem when using those kind of identifiers embedded inside normal text, like this:

```
The numbering_test database is too big.
```

Again the same problem with the HTML exporter.

Is there a way to tell the HTML exporter to put some text in raw mode, as provided, without adding extra HTML formatting to it?

Markdown (as used here in StackOverflow) has the very useful backticks to embed raw code inside normal text. I need something similar for org-mode.

Comment: I don't know org-mode, but have you tried `\_`?

Comment: Thanks, that works indeed. I would prefer a way of surrounding the raw area, like the backticks in markdown offer. Copy pasting from org-mode will be a hassle if I have escape codes in the middle of code sections.

Comment: I know, that's why I didn't write it as an answer! :"> Anyway, like I said, I don't have any idea what is org-mode!

Comment: I don't export my org files as html, so just shooting in the dark, here :( . Have you looked at (http://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-examples.html)? Since it's in a table, you might be able to use spreadsheet mode to output a literal string.

Comment: You might also be interested in this SO question (globally disable subscripting): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698562/disabling-underscore-to-subscript-in-emacs-org-mode-export

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are directives for org-export so it ignores the underscore as a subscript.

http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-options.html#Export-options

The one you are interested in is

```
#+OPTIONS:     ^:nil
```

which instructs the exporter to only sub/superscript text within explicit `{...}` brackets.

You can insert the whole template via the export dispatcher: `C-c C-e t`. Then you change/remove as will, and `C-c C-c` to refresh settings.

Comment: there is a typo. `C-c C-e t` instead of `C-x C-e t`