# Export a table to LaTeX and respect ^:nil

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I have an org file that isn't exporting to LaTeX the way I want it to. I am writing up a quiz to test job applicants' expertise with relational data. For clarity, I decided to go with column names strcutured as foo_bar. My example (below) includes a section called *Columns* and a section that is clearly a table. The underlines are working fine under *Columns* but they are showing as subscripts in the table. Why?

```
#+title: Relational Data
#+options: ^:nil toc:nil num:nil author:nil timestamp:nil

* tRemovalEpisodes
  A "removal" is a discrete event blah blah blah. This is all fine. 

  _Columns_
  - removal_id (int) is a Primary Key
  - child_id (int) is a Foreign Key
  - removal_date (date)
  - exit_date (date)
  - primary_removal_reason (int)

 | removal_id | child_id | removal_date |  exit_date | primary_removal_reason |
 |------------+----------+--------------+------------+------------------------|
 |          / |       <> |           <> |         <> |                     <> |
 |          1 |    12345 |   2012-01-01 | 2012-04-13 |                     13 |
 |          2 |    12346 |   2012-01-03 | 2013-02-14 |                     22 |
 |          3 |    12347 |   2012-04-02 |            |                     12 |
 |          4 |    12348 |   2012-09-05 | 2013-02-28 |                     13 |
 |          5 |    12349 |   2013-01-02 | 2013-04-12 |                     56 |
 |          6 |    12350 |   2013-03-01 |            |                     13 |
 |          7 |    12350 |   2012-01-01 | 2012-04-13 |                     14 |
 |          8 |    12351 |   2012-01-03 | 2013-02-14 |                     10 |
 |          9 |    12352 |   2012-04-02 |            |                     11 |
 |         10 |    12353 |   2012-09-05 | 2013-02-28 |                     11 |
 |         11 |    12345 |   2013-01-02 | 2013-04-12 |                     12 |
 |         12 |    12355 |   2013-03-01 |            |                     29 |
 |            |          |              |            |                        |

#+begin_latex
  \pagebreak
#+end_latex
```

Comment: What version of Org-Mode are you running?

Comment: 7.9.2, the default version in Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: I found this SO discussion, but it is different in that the OP didn't know how to get this affect. I just don't know why it is only working part of the time.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698562/disabling-underscore-to-subscript-in-emacs-org-mode-export?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it to export successfully under `Org 8.0.3`.

#### Export

```tex
\section*{tRemovalEpisodes}
\label{sec-1}
A "removal" is a discrete event blah blah blah. This is all fine. 

\underline{Columns}
\begin{itemize}
\item removal\_id (int) is a Primary Key
\item child\_id (int) is a Foreign Key
\item removal\_date (date)
\item exit\_date (date)
\item primary\_removal\_reason (int)
\end{itemize}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{r|r|r|r|r|}
removal\_id & child\_id & removal\_date & exit\_date & primary\_removal\_reason\\
\hline
1 & 12345 & 2012-01-01 & 2012-04-13 & 13\\
2 & 12346 & 2012-01-03 & 2013-02-14 & 22\\
3 & 12347 & 2012-04-02 &  & 12\\
4 & 12348 & 2012-09-05 & 2013-02-28 & 13\\
5 & 12349 & 2013-01-02 & 2013-04-12 & 56\\
6 & 12350 & 2013-03-01 &  & 13\\
7 & 12350 & 2012-01-01 & 2012-04-13 & 14\\
8 & 12351 & 2012-01-03 & 2013-02-14 & 10\\
9 & 12352 & 2012-04-02 &  & 11\\
10 & 12353 & 2012-09-05 & 2013-02-28 & 11\\
11 & 12345 & 2013-01-02 & 2013-04-12 & 12\\
12 & 12355 & 2013-03-01 &  & 29\\
 &  &  &  & \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

#### Updating

To upgrade to a newer version of Org-mode you can follow the instructions in the [Org FAQ](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#Keeping-current).

1. Download the release `zip` or `tarball` : [here](http://orgmode.org/index.html#sec-3)
2. Use git to keep up to date: `git clone git://www.orgmode.org/org-mode.git`
3. Use `ELPA` to install a more recent version.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. I upgrade org-mode tonight and see what I get. I find maintaining the plugins for tools like Emacs becomes increasingly complicated. Trying to keep one installation working where some parts are installed via apt-get and some via git becomes cumbersome. But, tihs is already how I'm keeping up with the Solarized theme, so I guess it isn't that different.